# insert the same line into excel file using batch script

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch

I am needing help with inserting the same line into an excel file and save it to a different directory. The file name and column D values will be different everytime but the rest will be the same for row 1 through 6. On Row 7, column D is taking an average of column D, row 2 through 6. Is there a batch script that will insert row 7, with the formula and save it to another directory?

| Analysis data | Element name | Symbol | Actual | Nominal | Deviation | U-Tol. | L-Tol. | O-Tol | OK/NG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.Roughness [Blast Position 1] |  | Ra | 3.5142 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |
| 2.Roughness [Blast Position 2] |  | Ra | 3.3612 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |
| 3.Roughness [Blast Position 3] |  | Ra | 3.5808 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |
| 4.Roughness [Blast Position 4] |  | Ra | 3.4778 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |
| 5.Roughness [Blast Position 5] |  | Ra | 3.3631 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |
| 6.Roughness [Blast Position Average] |  | Ra | 3.45942 |  |  | 50 | 2.1 |  | OK |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWF0.png)

Below is what I have tried, it inserts the information but is removing everything else.

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
Set Row=0 
( for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%A in ("C:\temp\Surfcom*.csv") do ( 
  Set /A Row+=7 
  If !Row! lss 6 (
    Rem new header 
    echo "Analysis data","Element Name","Symbol","Actual","Nominal","Deviation","U-Tol.","O-Tol","OK/NG" 
    ) Else 
    (Rem insert new empty rows 
    echo "6.Roughness [Blast Position Average]","","Ra","=Sum(D2:D6)/5","","","50","2.1","OK" 
    ) 
  ) 

) > "myfile.tmp" 
move /y "myfile.tmp" "myfile.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### it inserts the information but is removing everything else

That is what you have told it to do:

```
  If !Row! lss 6 (
    Rem new header 
    echo "Analysis data","Element Name","Symbol","Actual","Nominal","Deviation","U-Tol.","O-Tol","OK/NG" 
    ) Else 
    (Rem insert new empty rows 
    echo "6.Roughness [Blast Position Average]","","Ra","=Sum(D2:D6)/5","","","50","2.1","OK" 
    )
```

You are not copying the existing rows. try the following:

```
  If !Row! lss 6 (
    echo %%A
    ) Else 
    (Rem insert new row
    echo "6.Roughness [Blast Position Average]","","Ra","=Sum(D2:D6)/5","","","50","2.1","OK" 
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will give this a try and run some test. I currently have the below which is working, still need to get the loop added in with a delay. I ended up creating a template that held the data and merged two csv files into one which keeps the original naming.

Copy /b "C:\Insert directory\*.CSV"+ "C:\Location of template directory\Template.csv" "C:\New directory\"
Del "C:\Insert Directory (From line 1)\*.CSV"